# Schrodinger equation with $\hbar =1$

Tags: schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, dimensional-analysis, units, physical-constants

The Schrodinger equation is given by:
$$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle = H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle.$$
Sometimes, physicists set $\hbar=1$. I suppose that they achieve this by changing the scaling and dimensions of units.

I figured that one way of achieving $\hbar =1$ and dimensionless Schrodinger equation is defining dimensionless time $\tau := \frac{E}{\hbar}t$ and dimensionless Hamiltonian $\tilde{H}(t) := \frac{H(t)}{E}$ where $E$ could be maximum energy of $H(t)$ over all $t$. Substituting these definitions into the Schrodinger equation above yields:
$$i \frac{d}{d\tau}|\psi(\tau)\rangle = H(\tau)|\psi(\tau)\rangle.$$
So, we have $t = \frac{\hbar}{E}\tau $, which means that $\tau$ measures time in units of $\hbar/E$.

My reasoning: we have $d\tau = \frac{E}{\hbar}dt$ and $H(t) = E \tilde{H}(t)$. Then:
\begin{align}
i \hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle &= H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle\\
i \hbar \frac{d}{\frac{\hbar}{E}d\tau}|\psi(\tau)\rangle &= E\tilde{H}(\tau)|\psi(\tau)\rangle\\
 i\frac{d}{d\tau}|\psi(\tau)\rangle &= \tilde{H}(\tau)|\psi(\tau)\rangle.
\end{align}
I would like to know if this "rescaling" makes sense (or is common) and if it has a proper name.

It seems physicists take it as something trivial, but it took me a lot of time to figure this out, and I'm still not sure if this makes any sense.

Comment: There isn't a unique way to do this, but you've chosen to make time an inverse energy, whereas we normally make energy an inverse time, i.e. a frequency. Similarly, we make momentum an inverse length (i.e. a wavevector), but you could make length an inverse momentum.

Comment: In my experience, it’s not common to set only $\hbar$ to 1. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units) for a discussion of atomic units.

Comment: @MonteNero You get to choose whatever units you want. Since $\hbar$ is a dimensionful constant it will have a numerically different value when measured in different units. If you choose energy units of ergs and time units of years the numerical value of $\hbar$ is $3.34\times 10^{-35}$. If you choose energy units of electron-volts and time units of femto-seconds then the numerical value of $\hbar$ is 0.658. So, clearly you can arbitrarily adjust the numerical value of $\hbar$ by choosing different units. One system of units where $\hbar=1$ is called Hartree atomic units

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_units

Comment: Picking $E$ to be the "maximum energy of $H(t)$ over all $t$" is not a particularly well-defined concept, since $H$ is an operator and does not necessarily yield a definite energy.  Also, it'd be very hard to solve the problem using your system units without knowing what $E$ was, which would require you to have a solution of the problem in the first place.

Comment: @hft and others, thank you for the very helpful explanations and the wiki link. In the Wikipedia page that you provided, I found the table where the atomic unit of time is $\hbar/E_h$. I think this is similar to what I have, except $E_h$ seems to be a specifically chosen number. I guess, I could make my own choice for $E$?